# Waze "Share ETA" deep link

Tags: ios, deep-linking, waze

does anybody know what is the deep link to "Share ETA" with friend in Waze?
I couldn't find it anywhere. I want to use it in Siri Shortcuts.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't available at the moment, but it's reported as feature request at Waze HQ.